# Nginx proxy for webserver which is on different server where apache is dockerized

Tags: apache, nginx

I am on this scenario :

Server A (endpoint on DMZ) where running somes django apps through NGINX (on the same server), I have no trouble on those.

Server B (another local IP) where running two Docker's containers. One of them run apache, the other run PostGis.

I have already configure NGINX (server A) to get two django apps and pelican blog, from different subdomain. No trouble with them.

Apache in server B run a webapp on port 80. When I get the page to this server:port on my local network it's work properly.

It may be important to know that a redirection is done by apache and it's done on my browser.

What I need is to access server's B webapp from NGINX which is located on another subdomain.

I thought to add a new conf on NGNIX on A's server  could made the trick simply like this :

```
server {

listen [::]:80;
listen 80;

server_name sub.dns.com;

access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy-error.log;

location = / {
    # Instead of handling the index, just
    # rewrite / to /index.html
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.xx;

}
}
```

But when I try to get the page, I get a 404 Not found. But, I can see the redirection in the client browser .

this is the error in Nginx Log :

```
2016/11/30 13:30:39 [error] 23662#0: *6204 "/usr/share/nginx/html/websig/lizmap/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: IPxxx , server: [sub.dns.com] , request: "GET /websig/lizmap/ HTTP/1.1", host: "[sub.dns.com]"
```

I cannot figure out what's happening. I have not much experiences on NGINX and multiserver configuration. Please tell me if my question is not clever enought and if you need more info.

Comment: NGINX go to /usr/share/nginx/html/websig/lizmap/index.html to get the html page. But it should take the page from the Apache Containers. Don't know how to configure that

Comment: I find the reason of my trouble. The nginx block location on my server was declare as **=/** so I had to remove **=** to proxying all uri on the server B and it's workins as a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason of my trouble. The nginx block location on my server was declare as =/ so I had to remove = to proxying all uri on the server B and it's workins as a charm